# Merge data frames stored in list into single data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I start with list `l1`, which I want to convert to `output`. As such, the data frames in `l1` need to be merged by their first column (A).

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
              A B
              1 3
              2 4 ", header=T)
df2 <- read.table(text="
              A C
              1 8
              3 9 ", header=T)

l1 <- list(df1, df2); l1

output <- read.table(text="
              A B C
              1 3  8
              2 4  NA
              3 NA 9 ", header=T); output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
reduce(l1, merge, by = "A", all = TRUE)
```

This will work also in case if there is more then two data frames in the list.

Answer (score 0):

For a `baseR` option, try using `merge()` in outer join mode:

```
output <- merge(df1, df2, by = "A", all = TRUE)
```